# Is it possible for odbc driver, SQORA32.DLL , be either 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: oracle, odbc, database-connection, oracle12c

I recently downloaded the 12c oracle client 64bit (with ODBC drivers included during installation).

Afterwards, I opened both ODBC administrators, 32-bit and 64-bit, and only the ODBC administrator 64-bit list the Oracle driver (when adding a new System DSN) which makes me assume that only 64-bit Oracle driver was included; however, looking at the filename... it is named `SQORA32.DLL`. Is this a 64-bit odbc driver still? Can I disregard the name?

[image]

Comment: The 32bit Oracle Client contains only the 32bit ODBC driver, resp. the 64bit Client the 64bit ODBC driver. It must also the same "bitness" as your application, you cannot mix it. In case you need both, follow this instruction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the filename is strictly cosmetic, and doesn't mean anything with regards to the "bitness" of the DLL.

Once upon a time, `32` was used in file and directory names to help distinguish between 16-bit and 32-bit variants, but that fell by the wayside long ago.  `System32` does not indicate 32-bit content (though it is, on 32-bit systems); on 64-bit systems, it is full of 64-bit binaries.

Similarly, and even more confusingly, `SysWoW64` does not indicate 64-bit content.  In fact, `SysWoW64` indicates 32-bit content on 64-bit systems!

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit also, is the oracle odbc driver for 32-bit not included with installation of 64-bit 12c client? or is it not possible to have 32-bit odbc driver when with the 64-bit client..

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes, there are indeed many files named `*32.dll` in `System32`. This does not indicate that any of them are 32-bit binaries.

Comment: @Dip The 32-bit and 64-bit Oracle clients and ODBC drivers may both be present. However, they are delivered by different installers; one installer delivers the 32-bit Oracle client and ODBC driver, and another installer delivers the 64-bit.